# What Version of Bash comes with OSX 10.9 / Mavericks?

Tags: terminal, bash, macos

Trying to decide if I want to bother upgrading my bash shell to v4.x; if it comes with Mavericks, I probably won't, but I can't find much information on what versions of bash come with what versions of OS X, let alone with Mavericks specifically.

Anyone running a Mavericks beta want to `bash --version` for me?

Comment: I can't see it as much of a bother, install bash from macports and use that. Takes a couple minutes, you're not disturbing anything else, and you're not modifying your system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Zephyr:~ ats$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Zephyr:~ ats$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

Comment: For completeness sake, the same version is shipped with the release version of Mavericks.

Comment: and same for Yosemite and ElCapitan

Comment: And for those curious about Mojave, it's
`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @mjturner Not all releases, at least not anymore! 10.9.5 Build 13F1911 is `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`. I think it was updated to fix the ShellShock exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Wutas-Mac-mini:~ WJ$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

That should spell it out.

Comment: This answer is absolutely identical to the accepted answer which was posted and accepted eight months earlier. And it's improperly formatted. It should be deleted.